# Why can I not connect to my Windows VM via Chrome RDP on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rdp

I setup a Google Cloud VM instance with Windows and connected to it through RDP, which worked fine. Though when I quit the session and tried to access it again, I obtained the following error message:

Chrome RDP could not connect to '35.246.214.127'. Please try again.

[Error message by Chrome RDP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGTFM.png)

1. The instance is running (green light and stats are flashing on the dashboard).
2. I already checked the firewall settings as suggested and the required port permissions are granted.
3. The connection through SSH was also possible. But I need RDP to access running software on the GUI.

Comment: If you're connecting through Windows have you tried the Windows RDP client?

Comment: We need a more detailed error message as to why it won't connect. "It doesn't work" isn't enough info.

Answer (score 1):

To use RDP in a GCE Windows VM:

- Go to Compute Engine, and click in the arrow next to "RDP" > "Download RDP file".
- Then click in the arrow next to "RDP" > "Set Windows password" > "Set" > and copy the password.
- Then go to https://remotespark.com/view/rdp.html upload the file, set the user password, and connect.

Other option is enter in this VM > "Edit" > check "Enable connecting to serial ports" > "Save" > and then you can connect the VM through the serial port.

You can also try to restart the VM. Maybe your session still open and you could have a limit of only one user.
https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/dynamics365enterprisecloudfronts/posts/setup-simultaneous-remote-login-for-multiple-users